# PHP - Magento 2 load product by Sku code

Tags: php, magento2

I need to load products from Magento 2 using their SKU code (the id is not available at request time). The request is made via jQuery, and the response consists of a PHP file that fills dynamically the HTML page.
This is the request code (JavaScript):

```
function fetch_data(index, sku, price) {
  jQuery.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "magentoimporter.php",
      data: { sku: sku, price: price }
  })
  .fail(function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('FAIL product ' + index);
      }, 500);
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
      jQuery('.status').append(data+'<br/>');
  });
}
```

I have searched for a long time on the internet and I have found many guides and articles, which suggest the following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$product = $productRepository->get($sku_code);
```

However, after many attempts, I still receive one of these responses:

> 500 code (FAIL)
>
> 504 code (FAIL)
>
> Error page in the browser with a message in its console: "DevTools was disconnected from the page. One page is reloaded, DevTools will
> automatically reconnect."

It would be nice if someone could help me, I lost many hours trying to get over it. Thanks so much

Comment: For ajax request, Magento uses some rules. Your URL should be a path of a controller here. Please check out this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128669/how-to-make-a-simple-ajax-call-in-magento-2-1-0)

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on developer mode to see special error for this case

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

on the first line of index.php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);